# Job Scheduler libraries in Java Swing / Desktop

Tags: java, jar

I need to build a `job scheduler` for manufacturing items, which will be used to schedule a jobs depending upon the `Jobs` & `Datetime`. I don't have any idea which components will be helpful in `Java Swing application / desktop` & some other `resources` to create this sort of form.

Is there any library/jars exists to help me out to create this sort of requirements where user can schedule a job, can change a job like data bars?

Which components I can use to build scheduler, just like project scheduler?

Comment: Take a look at [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and go from there

Comment: any other tutorial, library or any other existing examples to implement scheduler will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long exploring options I found a solution of my problems through an existing libraries which is easy to integrate & controllable.

[Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is the best fitted option in my case.

### Quartz Scheduler’s APIs and Terminologies

**1. Scheduler: -**
The Primary API for scheduling, unscheduling, adding, and removing Jobs.

**2. Job: -**
The interface to be implemented by classes that represent a ‘job’ in Quartz. It has a single method called execute() where you write the work that needs to be performed by the Job.

**3. JobDetail: -**
A JobDetail represents an instance of a Job. It also contains additional data in the form of a JobDataMap that is passed to the Job when it is executed.
Every JobDetail is identified by a JobKey that consists of a name and a group. The name must be unique within a group.

**4. Trigger: -**
A Trigger, as the name suggests, defines the schedule at which a given Job will be executed. A Job can have many Triggers, but a Trigger can only be associated with one Job. Every Trigger is identified by a TriggerKey that comprises of a name and a group. The name must be unique within a group Just like JobDetails, Triggers can also send parameters/data to the Job.

**5. JobBuilder: -**
JobBuilder is a fluent builder-style API to construct JobDetail instances.

**6. TriggerBuilder: -**
TriggerBuilder is used to instantiate Triggers.